# Creating a slideshow in windows phone 8 without using pivot app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, pivot, slideshow

I'm writing a windows 8 app wich basically does nothing when you open it (everything is done in background task and the user doesn't see it) so I need to display a kind of slideshow on the main page of the app just so it looks like something and not just a blank page.
My problem is I can't use the pivot app template, I need to start from a blank template.
So I'd like to know what is the most simple way of doing this ? By the way, I need the slideshow to switch between the images automatically (with a timer that I can set) but the user can switch himself if he wants to
Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say You can't use the pivot app template and want to start using a blank template.

You can however add pivot as a control once you start with a blank template.
If Not using pivot is your aim, then try panorama.

Start from a blank template and add panorama control to it. Panorama can also help you to get a nice sliding effect like in a slideshow.

Answer (score 0):

you can have images in stackpanel and detect Flick Gestures whether left to right or viceversa through HorizontalVelocity of Flick events.